# knockoutjs foreach alias not working

Tags: knockout-2.0

The knockoutjs foreach alias does not work as explained in the [knockoutjs docs](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html) halfway down the page under:

`Note 3: Using “as” to give an alias to “foreach” items`

Here is a simple [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zvhzf/) showing the error. The console says that the alias is not defined although I've followed the knockoutjs example...

HTML

```
<h3>This works</h3>
<ul data-bind="foreach: people">
    <li>
        <span data-bind="text: $data.name"></span> 
        <span data-bind="text: $data.age"></span>
    </li>
</ul>

<h3>This doesn't work</h3>
<ul data-bind="foreach: { data: people, as: 'person' }">
    <li>
        <span data-bind="text: person.name"></span> 
        <span data-bind="text: person.age"></span>
    </li>
</ul>​
```

JS

```
var data = [
    { name: 'Bob', age: 35 },
    { name: 'Sue', age: 24 },
    { name: 'Rick', age: 57 }
];

var model = function( data ){
    this.people = ko.observableArray( data );
}
ko.applyBindings( new model( data ) );​
```

Am I just not understanding the example and doing something wrong? It's been known to happen, lol...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Upgrade to knockout 2.2.0 and it works. Upgraded fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/JkyWy/).

Your bindings are fine - leave them as-is:

```
<h3>This works</h3>
<ul data-bind="foreach: people">
    <li>
        <span data-bind="text: $data.name"></span> 
        <span data-bind="text: $data.age"></span>
    </li>
</ul>

<h3>This doesn't work</h3>
<ul data-bind="foreach: { data: people, as: 'person' }">
    <li>
        <span data-bind="text: person.name"></span> 
        <span data-bind="text: person.age"></span>
    </li>
</ul>​
```